# Determine, the distribution of $Z(w)=\left\{\begin{matrix} X(w)& \mbox{if}\ Y(w)\geq 0 \\ -X(w)&\mbox{if} \ Y(w)<0 \end{matrix}\right.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, stochastic-processes

Hey I want to check my solutions for this problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be standard normally distributed random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and define

$Z(w)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 X(w)& \mbox{if}\ Y(w)\geq 0 \\ 
 -X(w)&\mbox{if} \ Y(w)<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Why is Z a random variable? Determine, as concretely as possible, the distribution of Z.

So a random variable is a measurable function on a probabilty space. Therefore a construct of measurable functions is in turn a measurable function. Therefore is the construct of $Z(w)$ a random variable.

For the second part I have not so many ideas:
What I thougt is:

$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
  P_X(-X\leq z)=P_X(X\geq -z)=1-P_X(X\leq -z)=1-F_X(-z)&\mbox{if} \ Y(z)<0 \\
F_X(z)+(1-F_X(-z))& \mbox{if}\ Y(z)\geq 0
\end{matrix}\right.$

But I dont know if it is right. Can someone help me? Thanks :)

Comment: Try writing $P(Z\leq z)=P(Z\leq z,Y\geq0)+P(Z\leq z,Y>0)$. Maybe it's easier to continue from here?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. So I have $P(Z \leq z)=P(Z \leq z, Y \geq 0)+P(Z \leq z, Y > 0)=P(X \leq z)+P(-X \leq z)=P(X \leq z)+P(X \geq -z)=P(X \leq z)+(1-(P(X \leq -z))=\Phi(z)+(1-\Phi(-z))=\Phi(z)+(1-(1-\Phi(z)))=2\Phi(z)$ @jakobdt

Comment: Almost. Remember that $P(Z\leq z, Y\geq0)=P(X\leq z, Y\geq0)=\tfrac{1}{2}P(X\leq z)$ and similarly for $P(Z\leq z, Y>0)$. So in the end you get $P(Z\leq z)=\Phi(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(\exp(itZ))=E(\exp(itX)\mathbf{1}_{Y>0})+E(\exp(-itX)\mathbf{1}_{Y<0})$

Now $X$ and $-X$ are normally distributed(and hence have same characteristic functions) and independent of $Y$. and $E(\mathbf{1}_{Y>0})=P(Y>0)=\frac{1}{2}$

Hence the above is just $E(\exp(itZ))=\frac{1}{2}\phi(t)+\frac{1}{2}\phi(t)=\phi(t)$ where $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $X$.

Thus $Z$ and $X$ have same distribution.

In particular, in your method, you are not multiplying the probability($\frac{1}{2}$) of $Y$ being positive or negative. If you do, then you'll get the correct result.